# One SSL certificate for each subdomain and root redirection

Tags: redirect, ssl, https, certificate, subdomain

I am setting up a secure website with two subdomains:

```
https://www.domain.com
https://xxx.domain.com
```

I have acquired two SSL certificates, one for each of the subdomains (standard installation using nginx). I have also set up the root https://domain.com to simply redirect to https://www.domain.com.

Most of the time, this setup works fine. However, for some browsers (notably IE8 and Android), when accessing https://xxx.domain.com I get a certificate error, where the browser shows the certificate info for https://www.domain.com.
I suspect these browsers fetch the certificate from the root domain which then redirects to https://www.domain.com and hence the mismatch problem.

Can anyone advice on how to deal with this situation? Is buying a wildcard certificate the sole solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the same IP address for both, then yes, some sort of multiple name cert is the only practical solution at this point. Alternatively, if you run the xxx site on a different IP address, things should be okay.

This shouldn't be an issue for just IE and Android, though. I'm not sure what's up with that.

(Hmmm ... maybe this should be on serverfault).